# How to use useRef hook properly in react Functional Component?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-component

I have a JavaScript snippet and I'm trying to implement the same in react. Here is the snippet.

```
const nav = document.querySelector('.nav');
window.addEventListener('scroll', fixNav);

function fixNav() {
  if (window.scrollY > nav.offsetHeight) {
    nav.classList.add('active');
  } else {
    nav.classList.remove('active');
  }
}
```

For more details about the snippet, please refer this [codepen](https://codepen.io/VenkateshDharavath/pen/BapNXXj). When I scroll I'm just adding a class to the an element and removing when a certain condition is met using `scroll eventListerner`. Here is how I tried in react with the help of this official [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#refs-and-function-components).

```
const Navbar = () => {
    const navbar = useRef(null)
    window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
        if (window.scrollY > navbar.current.offsetHeight + 550) {
            navbar.current.classList.add('active');
        }else{
            navbar.current.classList.remove('active');
        }
    });
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <nav id='navbar' className="nav" ref={navbar}>
                <div className="container">
                    <h1 className="logo"><a href="/index.html"></a>My Website</h1>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#" className="current">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                     </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
            {/* other elements */}
        </Fragment>
    )
}
```

The error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetHeight' of null
```

So, the element `navbar` I'm trying to get is getting null when I actually scroll and the criterion in met. I could see the navbar element in the console when console.log it and the error as well at the same time. I'm sure I'm missing a fundamental concept behind the scenes.

If I'm trying to get the DOM element before the component is mounted, I must use `useEffect` to handle it properly. I'm new to react and not able to give it a good shot using `useEffect` hook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the event listener inside useEffect hook to make sure you access the ref after it has been assigned the dom element.

```
const Navbar = () => {
  const navbar = useRef(null);
  useEffect(()=>{
    window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
      if(navbar.current!==null){
        if (window.scrollY > navbar.current.offsetHeight + 550) {
          navbar.current.classList.add("active");
        } else {
          navbar.current.classList.remove("active");
        }
      }
    });
  },[]);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <nav id="navbar" className="nav" ref={navbar}>
        <div className="container">
          <h1 className="logo">
            <a href="/index.html"></a>My Website
          </h1>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#" className="current">
                Home
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Services</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
      {/* other elements */}
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

Comment: I tried `useEffect` but didnt wrap the eventListener inside the `if` condition. Thanks you.